# Different errors with different browsers in ajax call

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, jquery-plugins, jquery

What is the reason for this error? How do I fix?
error with Google Chrome :

> An error has occured: [object Object] parsererror SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token ILLEGAL

error with opera:

> An error has occured:  [object Object]  parsererror  SyntaxError:
>   JSON.parse: Unable to parse value:

error with ie9:

> An error has occured:  [object Object]  parsererror  SyntaxError:
>   Invalid character

and ...

js code:

```
$('#hotel').keypress(function () {
    var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/mehdi/admin/tour/search_hotel',
        data: dataObj,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#suggestion_tab").html('');
            $.each(data.suggestions, function (a, b) {
                $("#suggestion_tab").append('<li>' + data.b + '</li>');
            });
            // Display the results
            ///alert(data);
        },
        "error": function (x, y, z) {
            // callback to run if an error occurs
            alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
        }
        });
    });
```

php:(CI_Controller)

```
function search_hotel(){
    $searchterm = $this->input->post('search_hotel');
    $result = $this->model_tour->search_hotel($searchterm);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode(array('suggestions' => $output));
}
```

CI_Model

```
function search_hotel($searchterm)
{
    return mysql_query("select * from hotel_submits where name LIKE '".$searchterm."'");
}
```

Comment: This sound like your JSON response is invalid, how does it look?

Comment: check in the firebug what json do you get and verify that json with `www.jsonlint.com`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable for sql injection, check it before you put it on the web.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON contains invalid syntax.
You need to look at the actual JSON and fix the error.

Comment: Possible scenario: check JSON response string for control characters like newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure, that your response is in UTF.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to session timeout.

Answer (score -1):

Try using http://jsonlint.com/ to see if the JSON packet is valid. It looks to me like you need to json_encode every one of the rows from the database, and then add those encoded packets to another JSON array?

Comment: Not sure, that this will help -- response already json_encode`d